# How to generate JWT (JSON Web Token) from Azure Data Factory and then use it to get Acess Token to authenticate in Adobe API?

Tags: jwt, azure-data-factory, webapi

I want to ingest data from Adobe API that uses the JWT token to generate an Access token for authentication. Is there any way in the Azure data factory to generate the JWT token first and then that JWT token can be used to generate the Access token?

Comment: I am using this payload:  
{
"exp": 1550001438,
  "iss": ".....@AdobeOrg",
  "sub": ".....@techacct.adobe.com",
  "https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/s/ent_dataservices_sdk": true,
  "aud": "https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/c/API Key....."
}
But don't know how to use it in Azure data factory web activity to generate JWT Token

Comment: please edit your question if you have additional information. Posting these in comments makes no sense

Comment: I think the hard part is doing the RSASHA256 within Data Factory. I'm not sure this is possible.